# Copying Array With while Statement

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to write a program that is supposed to make a smiley slide to the left. I have developed the following code but when I run it it gives a very faulty print out.

```
void shiftMap (char sourceBitmap [8][8] , char destinationbitmap [8][8])
{

    for (int i = 0 ; i<8 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j<8 ; j++)
        {
            destinationbitmap [i][j] = sourceBitmap[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i<8 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<8 ; j++ )
        {
            if( destinationbitmap[i][j] == '1')
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", 'X');
            }

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
    char bitmap1 [8][8] =
    {
        {'1', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', 'X', 'X','1'},
        {'1', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', 'X', 'X','1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1'},
        {'X', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','X'},
        {'1', 'X', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'X','1'},
        {'1', '1', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '1','1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1'},
    };
    char bitmap2 [8][8] =
    {
        {'1', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', 'X', 'X','1'},
        {'1', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', 'X', 'X','1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1'},
        {'X', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','X'},
        {'1', 'X', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'X','1'},
        {'1', '1', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '1','1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1'},
    };

    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        system("cls");
        shiftMap(bitmap1,bitmap2);
    }
}
```

I am still really new to programming.

Comment: You should really have two functions: `shiftMap()` and `printMap()`, as they're two separate tasks (and maybe a third function, `copyMap()`).  After you've copied the shifted data once (when you fix the code to do a shift instead of a direct copy), you then need to copy the shifted data (`bitmap2`) back to the source (`bitmap1`) so that the next copy will start work on the shifted data.  As it stands, you're always shifting the same original version of `bitmap1` because it never changes.

Comment: Because you have two maps I am tempted to think you want to alternate two emoticons: smiley and sadly, as well as sliding across the display. The code just copies one to the other and prints the same thing for ever.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance your shiftMap function doesn't seem to do anything since your source and your destination are the same map and you assign destination[i][j] to source[i][j]. I don't know if this is what you intend but since you say you want it to slide left, i think you should change it to j-1 or something.

Comment: i did, but even then if i run it, it seems to do the same thing wich is verry strange :/

Comment: It doesn't do *anything* because `bitmap1` and `bitmap2` are identical, and regardless, when you copy `sourceBitmap` to `destinationbitmap` they would be identical then. You need an algorithm that shifts the values in each row or column by a desired about (presumably one). Also, do no use `printf ("\n");` (for any single character) use `putchar ('\n');` There is no need to call the variadiac `printf` to print one character.

Comment: what output do you get right now? If i were you I would just use one bitmap "matrix" and a variable that tells you where to start printing it which you initialize as zero and then increment by 1 every loop. This way you just change your while loop to a for loop (which is neater anyways). And then input that into your shiftMap function. Your shifMap can be reduced to the second nested for loop where the j variable starts at the input of shiftmap. I hope you understand what I'm saying.

Comment: Given the current makeup of the bitmaps, your only option is to shift the rows down by `1` a maximum of `2` times before returning to the original. You can't shift left/right and maintain the image.

Comment: @Xentro i think i have a rough idea of what you are saying. but could you maby tel me how to let the array increment by 1 every loop? maby if you can type the code so i can understand it more clearly.

Comment: change your while-loop to a for-loop. Change your shifMap function so it takes a bitmap and an int as input, you then call shiftMap(bitmap1, k) (with k being the variable in your for-loop for example). Then remove the first part of your shiftmap implementation and change second for-loop to: for(int j = k; j<8; j++)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment, nothing is happening because `bitmap1` and `bitmap2` are identical. Further, in `shiftmap` you are overwriting `bitmap2` with `bitmap1` destroying any difference that may exist. Yet another challenge is the fact that the only shift that can occur is to *row-shift* the bitmap down by `1` a maximum of `2` times before destroying your smiley.

Given that setup, the easiest way to get a *"shift"* up/down of your smiley is to modify `bitmap2` putting the smiley lower by (`1` or `2` rows) and then simply toggling between the printing of `bitmap1` and `bitmap2`. For example, you could very simply accomplish that with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void prnmap (char (*bitmap)[8])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            if (bitmap[i][j] == '1')
                putchar (' ');
            else
                putchar ('X');
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

int main (void) {

    char bitmap1[][8] = {
        {'1', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', 'X', 'X', '1'},
        {'1', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', 'X', 'X', '1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'},
        {'X', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'X'},
        {'1', 'X', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'X', '1'},
        {'1', '1', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '1', '1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'},
    };
    char bitmap2[][8] = {
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'},
        {'1', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', 'X', 'X', '1'},
        {'1', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', 'X', 'X', '1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'},
        {'X', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'X'},
        {'1', 'X', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'X', '1'},
        {'1', '1', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '1', '1'},
    };
    int toggle = 0, n = 5;

    while (n--) {               /* do 5 iterations */
        if (toggle & 1)         /* if odd, bitmap1 */
            prnmap (bitmap1);
        else                    /* even, bitmap2   */
            prnmap (bitmap2);
        toggle ^= 1;            /* toggle 0,1,0,.. */
        sleep (1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(Which simply causes the smiley to bounce up/down by two rows each iteration)

Also, while not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids `caMelCase` variables in favor of all *lower-case*. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf) Leave `camelCase` to C++.

Further, as mentioned in the comments, there is never a need to call `printf` to print a *single-character*. `printf` is a complex variadic function meant to print formatted strings. `putchar` (or `fputc`) are simple functions and all that is needed to print a *single-character*.

Look over the code, look at the output and let me know if that is what you were trying to accomplish. If not, we can work on another algorithm that actually shifts the values within the bitmaps.

Comment: i get an error on the sleep function. i get " unidentified refference to `sleep' "

Comment: You can use your sleep function. Did you include `unistd.h`? (note: the `sleep` function is a POSIX function and not part of the standard C-library, your compiler may not implement it.)